# What steps in the conlang process am I missing?

Tags: conlang-creation

My currently known process for conlanging is 1) set goals, 2) define phonology, 3) Romanize, 4) phonotactics, 5) define word order, 6) define morphosyntactic alignment, 7) define morphology type, 8) create list of basic root words, 9) phonological evolution and new word derivation

Is there anything I am missing? Should I reorder any of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that "word order" and "morphosyntactic alignment" and "morphology type" are broad categories used to make generalizations about natural language. Saying that English is SVO can be a useful shorthand, but that ignores everything that makes English syntax interesting!

These broad categories are a starting point, laying out the basic groundwork for you. But it won't give you anything unique or individual about your particular language. That part is up to you.

So I would replace those steps with figuring out the syntax and morphology in general. Don't limit yourself to Greenberg's universals—because often, linguistic "universals" aren't. And this goes double for conlangs.